# Matching variables by suffix, jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, string-matching

I have a script that adds/removes a class to two elements, and shows/hides a third element, if a certain term is found in a text-input field on keyup. The three elements in question are a span, a text-input, and a div. But I have five sets of them, and I want to be able to write the script only once for all five sets, but have it only affect the current set of three elements. I tried using the starts with selector, but it applies the changes to all five sets. Is there a way to have it apply the changes only if the selectors' suffixes match?

The sets all have IDs that end in "base1" or "base2", etc., up to five. Here's the current script:

```
$('input[id^=base]').keyup(function() {
    var str = $('input[id^=base]').val(); 
    var i = $('input[id^=base]');       
    var s = $('span[id^=ssfa-abspath-base]');
    var e = $('div[id^=ssfa-error-base]');

    if (/wp-admin/i.test(str) || /wp-includes/i.test(str)) {
        $(i).addClass('ssfa-error');
        $(s).addClass('ssfa-error');
        $(e).show(600);         
   }
    else{
        $(i).removeClass('ssfa-error');
        $(s).removeClass('ssfa-error');         
        $(e).hide(600);

   }
```

Then the html is just basically: `span1 > input1 > div1 <br> span2 > input2 > div2 <br>` etc.

*EDIT*

To try to be clearer:

Set 1:

```
<span id=something-base1></span><input id=base1></input><div id=something-else-base1></div>
```

Set 2:

```
<span id=something-base2></span><input id=base2></input><div id=something-else-base2></div>
```

*etc*

I want to write the script just once, rather than five times, once for each set. To do so, I need it to group them based on suffixes, so it only applies the class changes to the current set (where the matched value of "wp-admin" or "wp-includes" is found in the text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track but once you're in the `keyup` handler, you only want to deal with the specific element / set of elements in question. For example

```
$('input[id^=base]').each(function() {
    var idSuffix = this.id,
        i = $(this),
        s = $('#ssfa-abspath-' + idSuffix),
        e = $('#ssfa-error-' + idSuffix),
        rx = /wp-(admin|includes)/i;

    i.on('keyup', function() {
        var test = rx.test(i.val());

        i.toggleClass('ssfa-error', test);
        s.toggleClass('ssfa-error', test);
        if (test) {
            e.show(600);
        } else {
            e.hide(600);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/buQNp/